# CoreData fetched property and RestKit 0.20.3: value for undefined key

Tags: core-data, xcode5, restkit, restkit-0.20, fetched-property

I'm facing a big issue with fetched properties.

I have this entities in the model:

```
EntityDetail    
Attributes:
NSString: idd_info
[...]
Fetched Property:
Name: info Destination: EntityInfo Predicate: idd==$FETCH_SOURCE.idd_info


EntityInfo
Attributes:
NSString: idd
NSString: title
[...]
```

In this way I can obtain related EntityInfo when I need:

```
[[detail.info objectAtIndex:0] title]
```

I prefer this approach instead of configuring a regular relationship due to performance reasons during the parsing process.

If I use the Apple generated CoreData boilerplate to setup the stack, everything works fine and I can use the fetched property with success. But if I use the RestKit provided implementation by the RKManagedObjectStore class, the fetched property does not work. This is the error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSObjectID_48_15 0x1a2f9ac0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key idd_info.'**

It seems that $FETCH_SOURCE resolves to a NSObjectID instead of the NSObject itself. And, obviously, the idd_info property is not defined on that class.

Googling around I found the possibility to setup the resultType on a fetchRequest to NSManagedObjectResultType. This is the default behavior as stated in Apple documentation. So why does RestKit 0.20.3 use NSManagedObjectIDResultType instead? With RestKit 0.10 everything works fine...

Is this a know bug? How can I force the fetched property to NSManagedObjectResultType ?

This is the way I setup the persistent stores and create managed object context using RKManagedObjectStore.
I am in the application delegate and _managedObjectModel _managedObjectStore _managedObjectContext are singleton variables used in the whole app).

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"momd"]];        
_managedObjectModel= [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy]; 
_managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];     
[_managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];


NSString *storePath = [[self docDir] stringByAppendingPathComponent::@"MyApp.sqlite"];    
NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };    
NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [_managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:options error:&error];    
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);


[_managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];        
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:_managedObjectStore];    
[_managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];    
_managedObjectContext = _managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

If I use:

```
_managedObjectContext = _managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
```

instead of:

```
_managedObjectContext = _managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

in the application delegate at startup the issue doesn't occurs and fetched property works fine, but it still occurs during mapping.

This is how I set up the mapping.

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeTextXML];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:appDeleg.managedObjectModel];

[objectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:@{ NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} } error:nil];

[objectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

objectManager.managedObjectStore=objectStore;

[objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:usernameString password:passwordString]

[... here RKEntityMappings and ResponseDescriptors added to the objectManager ...]

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  getObjectsAtPath:remoteBaseAddedPath parameters:nil

    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {


            [delegate parserDidSuccessParsingData:self];


    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {



            [delegate parserDidFailParsingData:self withError:error];

}];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the stack trace during mapping. Please note that I have a transient property on the object which uses the fetched property in the getter, RestKit call this getter and crash occurs:

```
2014-03-20 11:10:53.545 MyApp[15378:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-03-20 11:10:53.549 MyApp[15378:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSTemporaryObjectID_default 0xcb9a870> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key idd_info.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b021e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028818e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b91fe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00f6dc7a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x00edadfd _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
    5   Foundation                          0x00eda437 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 260
    6   Foundation                          0x00ef9f0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 409
    7   Foundation                          0x00eab465 -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 1260
    8   CoreData                            0x00728bbc -[NSSQLSimpleWhereIntermediate initWithPredicate:inScope:] + 620
    9   CoreData                            0x007283eb -[NSSQLGenerator generateWhereIntermediatesInContext:] + 187
    10  CoreData                            0x00727dc1 -[NSSQLGenerator generateIntermediatesForFetchInContext:countOnly:] + 673
    11  CoreData                            0x007242f3 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 483
    12  CoreData                            0x00723fb8 -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 472
    13  CoreData                            0x00723dd0 -[NSSQLAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:] + 48
    14  CoreData                            0x00723b91 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 129
    15  CoreData                            0x0072331d -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 701
    16  CoreData                            0x00722dcf -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 383
    17  CoreData                            0x007227f2 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 4466
    18  CoreData                            0x0071ff56 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 566
    19  CoreData                            0x00774d86 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 502
    20  CoreData                            0x007f2a14 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 676
    21  CoreData                            0x00774b81 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 17
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x032394d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03226740 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 58
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x032263ea dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 89
    25  CoreData                            0x00774b02 _perform + 114
    26  CoreData                            0x007749ae -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 238
    27  CoreData                            0x0071ff56 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 566
    28  CoreData                            0x00774d86 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 502
    29  CoreData                            0x007f2a14 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 676
    30  CoreData                            0x00774b81 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 17
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x032394d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03228439 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 80
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x032394d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03227726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x02b6743e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa85cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa79d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa77eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x0392c5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x0392c42b GSEventRun + 104
    41  UIKit                               0x012bff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    42  MyApp                               0x001a186c main + 76
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x0346e701 start + 1
    44  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: RestKit is not involved with the creation of your fetch request and offers only a wrapper around the creation of the Core Data stack so I can't see any difference there. Unless you're trying to use the fetched property during mapping?

Comment: That's what I thought. The issue occurs during mapping. BUT if I use RKManagedObjectStore to create the CoreData stack, the issue occurs ALSO when I use the fetched property everywhere, outside the mapping process. If I replace the code above with regular Coredata boilerplate everything works like a charm!

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the crash and can you debug to check the fetch that is executed?

Comment: When it works using the persistent store context, you get results back? You didn't add the mappings - where is `info` fetched property used in the mappings? I expect use during mapping could cause issues, but why would you need to use it during mapping? Did you actually observe performance issues with relationships?